# Chrome using over 50% of my memory / virtual memory

Tags: google-chrome, windows-xp

Chrome is taking all my laptop memory and virtual memory.

A staggering 700mb, and in some cases even more memory.

For eg.. My Task manger is showing 9 chrome.exe’s open when I only have one chrome browser open with 3 live tabs and 1 blank tab

Any advice as to why (this is happening) and how can I resolve this.

My laptop has crashed 5 times in the last week "blue screen nightmare" and now I am desperate to find a solution before my laptop is damaged and I lose my data.

Laptop Spec ~ Lenovo x61s, XP SP3, 2gb RAM

Comment: [Try running Chrome with all plugin disabled.](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/extensions_broke_your_browser_how_to_enter_safe_mo.php). Chrome runs plugins in their own process, which explains some of those apparently extraneous ones. If memory usage is significantly lower with plugins disabled, the next step would be to figure out which plugin it is - update your question if this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> will let you see where all this memory is spent, there you can end the processes you don't need with the button in the lower right bottom. The lower left bottom leads to nerd statistics which can also be accessed by visiting `chrome://memory-redirect/`

Answer (score 0):

700MB? That's on par what what's out there. It totally depends on the sites you are visiting, but essentially a new instance of the web browser is created for that website (think, instead of 3 windows you only have 1 but with 3 browser windows embedded inside it). Internet Explorer uses the most RAM, then firefox and lastly google chrome (I remember reading up on some stats a while ago, 40 windows in firefox take up 1.2gb ram).

A major issue you are facing is probably the fact you only have 2gb ram where the operating system uses up more than a GB of ram, not including the other programs/services you are running. The most efficient Windows OS at the moment is windows 8 using only about 300-400MB of RAM.

Comment: He's running Windows XP, which lists a minimum of 64mb RAM with 128mb recommended. And, though it's not really possible to compare browsers like that, I currently have about 60 superuser tabs open in FF at 650mb. Keeping everything in one process reduces overhead a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You're always likely to struggle if you try to run 2012 software on 2007 hardware and a 2001 operating system. It may be time for an upgrade. If that's not feasible, then I'd look for an old browser version, although watch out for unpatched security vulnerabilities.